# php sql Displaying images from different contributors

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am trying to create a gallery with a list of users (all links) pulled from a users table (userId, userName, userEmail and userPass) in my database. When the user uploads a photo it save to a uploads directory but the information saves to a database table called images (imgId, userId, imgName, imgLocation and uploadDate). What i want to do is have a list of users pulled from the users table and when you click a user it displays only the photos they have uploaded.

I have this code so far for displaying users in list as links.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

// if session is not set this will redirect to login page
if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
// select loggedin users detail
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM `users`");

echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo    '<tr>
        <td class="userlist"><font size="4" face="Lucida Sans Unicode"color="black"><a href="" >'.$rowtwo['userName'].'</a></td>
        </tr>';
   }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I don't know how to link the users to the images, and then display the images to the right of the list of users. I want to use the userId which is saved to the images table whenever a image is submitted, but i am completely lost.

Any help would be great(if i have made any sense), still fairly new to this.

Comment: Can you please explain to me in two clear sentences what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a list of signed up users on the left of my page each username is a link, I want to be able to press the username and be able to see all of the photos that user has uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking the user, send the userId in the request and fetch the images from the images table using this query,

```
select 'imgName', 'imgLocation' from images where userId = '$YourUserId';
```

then using a loop you can display images by looping  tag,

```
<img src="IMAGE_LOCATION" alt="IMAGE_NAME" height="42" width="42">
```